# How to handle authorization code requests in react-native?

Tags: react-native, axios, interceptor, two-factor-authentication

I have a case where server could respond with error if authorization code is required (for example code from Google Authenticator) and I can't find a solution on how to handle that.

Scenario: Request to server > server responds with error > enter code > re-send request with added code in body

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would do it this way: 
Send request to server > 
Receive error and open another window, which will contain the text box for  the code > 
User fills it out and sends it >
Then if it was successful, display a message or navigate to another screen.

If this isn't the answer you are looking for then please specify your question more clearly...

Comment: Yup, that is correct

The problem is that this has to happen in interceptor, and react-native doesn't have things like promise based modal or something to call from interceptor.

This has to handled like this > Interceptor gets error > shows modal > puts user input in to same request body that got error > returns updated request